# Why is my c++ build saying I have in "invalid character in path"?

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I'm trying to build my first c++ program, and I'm using the Eclipse plugin for it. I'm using their example "Hello world" program. It doesn't show any errors, but when I hit build, it logs the following:

> **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Hello world ****
>
> **** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
>
> Build error
>
> Illegal character in path at index 5: Hello world.exe

Does anybody know why this error is occurring, or how to fix it?

Thanks :)

EDIT:

I tried creating my own, and I'll add a pic below of my file structure, but now I get the following error: (im assuming its an error as it still won't run, but it might not be)

> **** Build of configuration Debug for project Project ****
>
> **** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
>
> Nothing to build for Project

[image: File structure]

Comment: try replacing the `<white space>` to `_`

Comment: It is possible that your toolchain does not like spaces. It is also possible that in the project build settings, the output filename is not using a "normal" space character, but a variant such as a non-breaking space character which is not allowed in filenames. In either case, you should change the output filename.

Comment: @AnthonyBurleigh I tried making a new project which didn't use spaces, and that didn't appear to help

Comment: Correction; that did help, and I think may have resolved that error, but still nothing is printed; any obvious mistake in that code or something?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the first part of the answer was to remove the space in the filename, as per the comment responses.  I suspect your problem with "not outputting" is that the program prints and exits really fast (this is a gotcha that got me when I first started programming in C++).  To fix this problem, try adding the following line after your cout statement:

```
sleep(5); // Wait 5 seconds before exiting the program
```